# python: help working with csv file

Tags: python, csv

I need some help working with a csv file in Python. The csv file contains date and temperature information. I'm hoping to have the user enter a date and then I want to find all the temperatures in the csv file that correspond to the date that the user entered and average the temperature.

When I run this code, I don't get any error messages, but nothing seems to happen. I'm not sure how to fix this.

My csv file is set up like this, except much longer and there are many temperature values for each date:

[image]

```
import csv
import math

date = float(raw_input("Please enter a date within the past three days (format: for 12/2/15, enter '02'): "))

with open('temp1.csv', 'rb') as csvfile_temp1:
    reader1 = csv.reader(csvfile_temp1)
    for row in reader1: 
        if (row[2]) == date:
            print (row[3])
            w_temp1 = [float(row[3]) for row in reader1]
            average1 = sum(w_temp1) / len(w_temp1)
            print (average1)
```

Comment: When asking for help, more info is better than less. I suggest adding the exact (but shortened) csv file in text format, not a picture of the data in tabular format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your problem is that the variable `date` is of type `float` while `row[2]` is of type `str`. Try skipping the cast to `float`.

```
date = float(...)  # type(date) == <type 'float'>
...
for row in reader1: 
    if (row[2]) == date:  # type(row[2]) == <type 'str'>
```